# Google App Script can't capitalise a variable using .toUppercase()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a variable defined:

```
var capitaliseMe = "this is an example";
```

I want to replace text in the header of a Google Doc with the capitalised form of this variable.

I tried using the following

```
header.replaceText("{{ReplaceMe}}", capitaliseMe.toUppercase());
```

but this doesn't seem to be working as I get the error

> TypeError: capitaliseMe.toUppercase is not a function

There doesn't seem to be a comprehensive answer to this anywhere on Stack Overflow or elsewhere online, so some help with capitalisation would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
header.replaceText("{{ReplaceMe}}", capitaliseMe.toUpperCase());
```

C is case was not capitalized.  Its called camel code.

[toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)